# java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve transation read-only status server and take a few hours for the persist to return failure

Tags: mysql

The insert query failed after a few hours....

Here's the error log:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve transation
>   read-only status server
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1084) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:973) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:918) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:949) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:939) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.isReadOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:3976)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.isReadOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:3947)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2295)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2262)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2246)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
>       at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1449)
>   ~[c3p0-0.9.5.jar:0.9.5]
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
>   ~[hibernate-core-4.3.10.Final.jar:4.3.10.Final]
>       ... 37 common frames omitted Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure
>
> The last packet successfully received from the server was 8,378,053
>   milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was
>   8,378,052 milliseconds ago.
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_40]
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_40]
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_40]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1127)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3715) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.reuseAndReadPacket(MysqlIO.java:3604) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4155) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2615) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2832) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2781) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1569)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.isReadOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:3970)
>   ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:na]
>       ... 43 common frames omitted Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out
>       at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_40]

Comment: Were you able to figure out the problem? I am seeing the same error after a certain period.